# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\sin(\theta)}{2-\sin(\theta)}d\theta$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, residue-calculus

I've been studying for a complex analysis exam and I came across this exercise, but I'm not sure how to go about solving this integral. Is there a way to substitute something to change the $\theta$ to something more workable? It seems we're integrating along a unit circle, so maybe we could change the variable back to z with a substitution and use the Residue theorem on what's left?

Comment: Hint: Remember how to write the sine in complex form.

Comment: **Not** using complex analysis, you might be able to solve this by writing the integrand as $$\dfrac{\frac{\sin x}2}{1-\frac{\sin x}2}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^kx}{2^k}$$

Comment: If you are expected to know this for your exam, I should think you would have been given examples of the standard method for this, which is to substitute $z=e^{i\theta}$.  That should work fine here.

Comment: Just a comment - there is also the Weierstrass substitution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This (class of) problem is standard---see the remark below---but surprisingly a cursory search didn't turn up any questions with answers that applied directly.

Setting $$z = e^{i \theta}$$ transforms the integral into the contour integral along the unit circle, $S^1$. In particular we have $$\sin \theta = \frac{1}{2 i}(e^{i \theta} - e^{-i \theta}) = \frac{1}{2 i}\left(z - \frac{1}{z}\right) .$$

(We don't need it in this case, but for the same reason $\cos \theta = \frac{1}{2} \left(z + \frac{1}{z}\right)$.)

Now, $dz = i e^{i \theta} d\theta$, so $$d\theta = \frac{dz}{i z} ,$$ and hence

$$\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{\sin \theta}{2 - \sin \theta}\,d\theta = \frac{1}{i}\oint_{S^1} \frac{\frac{1}{2 i}(z - \frac{1}{z})}{2 - \frac{1}{2 i}(z - \frac{1}{z})} \frac{dz}{z} = i \oint_{S^1} \frac{z^2 - 1}{z (z^2 - 4 i z + 1)} \,dz.$$
At this point we're prepared to apply the Residue Theorem.

**Remark** The change $z = e^{i \theta}$ of variable transforms any definite integral of a rational function of $\sin \theta, \cos \theta$ over the interval $[0, 2\pi]$ into a contour integral of a rational function of $z$ along $S^1$, hence in principle any such integral can be evaluated with the Residue Theorem.

Answer (score 4):

**Without complex**
$$
\begin{aligned}
 \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{\sin \theta}{2-\sin \theta} d \theta = & \int_0^{2 \pi}\left(\frac{2}{2-\sin \theta}-1\right) d \theta \\
= & 2 \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{d \theta}{2-\sin \theta}-2 \pi
\end{aligned}
$$
Splitting the integration interval gives
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{d \theta}{2-\sin \theta} & =\int_0^\pi \frac{d \theta}{2-\sin \theta}+\int_\pi^{2 \pi} \frac{d \theta}{2-\sin \theta} \\
& =\int_0^\pi \frac{2 \theta}{2-\sin \theta}+\int_0^\pi \frac{d \theta}{2+\sin \theta} \\
& =4 \int_0^\pi \frac{d \theta}{4-\sin ^2 \theta}\\&= 8 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sec ^2 \theta}{4 \sec ^2 \theta-\tan ^2 \theta} d \theta
\end{aligned}
$$
Letting $t=\tan \theta$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{d \theta}{2-\sin \theta} & =8 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{d t}{4+3 t^2} \\
& =\frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}\left[\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{3} t}{2}\right)\right]_0^{\infty} \\
& =\frac{2 \pi}{\sqrt{3}}
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence we can conclude that
$$
\boxed{\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{\sin \theta}{2-\sin \theta} d \theta=\frac{4 \pi}{\sqrt{3}}-2 \pi=2 \pi\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}-1\right)}
$$

Answer (score 3):

**Contour integration**

Let $ z=e^{i \theta}$, then $d \theta=\frac{d z}{i z}$ and
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{d \theta}{2-\sin \theta}&=\oint_{|z|=1} \frac{d z}{i z\left(2-\frac{z-z^{-1}}{2 i}\right)} \\
& =-2 \oint_{|z|=1} \frac{d z}{z^2-4 i z-1} \\
& =-2 \oint_{|z|=1} \frac{d z}{[z-(2+\sqrt{3}) i][z-(2-\sqrt{3}) i]} \\
& =-4 \pi i \operatorname{Res}_{z =(2-\sqrt{3}) i}\left(\frac{1}{z^2-4 i z-1}\right)  \\
& =-4 \pi i\left[\frac{i}{2 \sqrt{3}}\right] \\
& =\frac{2 \pi}{\sqrt{3}} \\
&
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence

\begin{aligned}
 \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{\sin \theta}{2-\sin \theta} d \theta = \int_0^{2 \pi}\left(\frac{2}{2-\sin \theta}-1\right) d \theta = \frac{4 \pi}{\sqrt{3}}-2\pi
\end{aligned}

Answer (score 1):

Using [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula),

$$\begin{align*}
\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sin\theta}{2-\sin\theta} \, d\theta &= \oint\limits_{|z|=1} \frac{\frac{z-\frac1z}{2i}}{2-\frac{z-\frac1z}{2i}} \, \frac{dz}{iz} \\
&= i \oint\limits_{|z|=1} \frac{z^2-1}{z\left(z^2-4iz-1\right)} \, dz \\
&= i \underbrace{\oint\limits_{|z|=1} \frac {dz}z}_{=2\pi i\cdot1} + \frac{2i}{\sqrt3} \underbrace{\oint\limits_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{z-(2+\sqrt3)i}}_{=0} - \frac{2i}{\sqrt3} \underbrace{\oint\limits_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{z-(2-\sqrt3)i}}_{=2\pi i\cdot1} \\ 
&= \left(\frac4{\sqrt3}-2\right)\pi
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Using Weierstrass substitution**

To avoid discontinuity of the substitution $t=\tan \frac{\theta}{2}$, we first change the integration interval $[0, 2\pi]$ to $[-\frac{\pi}{2} , \frac{\pi}{2}]$ as below:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{1}{2-\sin \theta} d \theta & =2 \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{2-\sin \theta} d \theta \\
& =2 \int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{2-\frac{2 t}{1+t^2}} \frac{2 d t}{1+t^2} \\
& =2 \int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{t^2-t+1} d t \\
& =8 \int_{-1}^1 \frac{d t}{(2 t-1)^2+(\sqrt{3})^2} \\
& =\frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}\left[\tan \left(\frac{2 t-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\right]_{-1}^1 \\
& =\frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}\left(\frac{\pi}{6}+\frac{\pi}{3}\right) \\
& =\frac{2 \pi}{\sqrt{3}}
\end{aligned}
$$